# Number of working days between two dates in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Could anyone please help with generating number of working days between two dates in Google Apps Script.
Thank you.

Comment: The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090867/how-do-i-calculate-number-of-given-weekday-between-range-using-moment-js shows both how to do it in momentjs and vanilla js. The momentJS apps script library is MHMchiX6c1bwSqGM1PZiW_PxhMjh3Sh48.

Comment: Really its a dup of that question. Its not particular to apps script. Pure javascript

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer given here: [How do I calculate number of given weekday between range using Moment JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090867/how-do-i-calculate-number-of-given-weekday-between-range-using-moment-js)
It works similar in AppsScript

```
function workdays_between(start_date_string, end_date_string) {
  var startDate = new Date(start_date_string)
  var endDate = new Date(end_date_string)

  // Validate input
  if (endDate <= startDate) { return 0; }

  // Calculate days between dates
  var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; // Day in milliseconds
  startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 1);  // Start just after midnight
  endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);  // End just before midnight
  var diff = endDate - startDate;  // Milliseconds between datetime objects    
  var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);

  // Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
  var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
  days -= weeks * 2;

  // Handle special cases
  var startDay = startDate.getDay();
  var endDay = endDate.getDay();

  // Remove weekend not previously removed.   
  if (startDay - endDay > 1) { days -= 2; }
  // Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
  if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6) { days--; }
  // Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
  if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0) { days--; }

  return days
}

function test_it() {
  let start_date_string = "March 12, 2021"
  let end_date_string = "October 15, 2021"
  console.log(workdays_between(start_date_string, end_date_string) + " workdays between " + start_date_string + " and " + end_date_string)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

From user KBA (https://stackoverflow.com/users/453331/kba) from response [How do I calculate number of given weekday between range using Moment JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090867/how-do-i-calculate-number-of-given-weekday-between-range-using-moment-js):

```
var firstDate = new Date("March 1, 2015");
var secondDate = new Date("March 25, 2015");

function getWeekdaysBetweenDates(firstDate, secondDate, dayOfWeek) {
    var MILISECONDS_IN_DAY = 86400000;

    function getNextDayOfWeek(date, dayOfWeek) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + (7 + dayOfWeek - date.getDay()) % 7);
        return date;
    }

    firstDate = getNextDayOfWeek(firstDate, dayOfWeek);
    if (firstDate > secondDate) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1 + Math.floor(((secondDate - firstDate) / MILISECONDS_IN_DAY) / 7);
}
```