# How to get workdays between dates using javascript function from a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to get workdays between dates using javascript function from a spreadsheet

```
function dateTest() {

    var template=SpreadsheetApp.openById('280337105')

    var test = template.getSheetByName('Consultants');

    var database =SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Prospect33');

    var startDate = database.getRange('C7').getValue();

    var endDate = database.getRange('E7').getValue();

    test.getRange('M7').setValue(startDate);

    test.getRange('N7').setValue(endDate);

    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28425663/4717755) ?

Comment: @PeterT yes i have but when tried gives the error moment undefined

Comment: Austine, have you included the moment.js lib as a dependency to your project?

Comment: The link I provided requires using the `momentjs` package. Using some sort of packaged date/time manipulation functions is [highly reccommened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1214753/4717755). Pick your package and give it a try.

Comment: How much research have you done? There are dozens of questions like this on StackOverflow. Look at: [Number of working days between two dates in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350307/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate number of given weekday between range using Moment JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090867/how-do-i-calculate-number-of-given-weekday-between-range-using-moment-js)