# Select some days from range dates array JavaScript and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]
I am doing a schedule for users to be shown in a calendar.
I have a JavaScript function that gets a range between 2 dates. and I have 7 buttons on the HTML page , each one named by a day for Sun, Mon, Tue....
How to push in an array the selected days dates by user from the selected range dates date picker

```js
function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = [];
  var currentDate = moment(startDate);
  var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
  }
  return dateArray;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="ashrafdays ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="Listdatas.Sundy" id="IsSunday">
  <label ng-show="!Listdatas.Sundy" class="title_lable sun_ico ng-hide" for="IsSunday" id="sun_ico" style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
  <label ng-show="Listdatas.Sundy" class="title_lable sun_ico_g" for="IsSunday" id="sun_ico" style="font-weight:bold;">         </label>
</div>
```

Comment: pls clarify your question. are you asking how to filter the data in your table by day of the week? If I choose a 2 week range and then click the Monday button, what is the xpected result? Also, please show the html for that table, and the JS for any filtering that is already happening on that table. Thx

Comment: Thanks for replying                        1- The user will choose 2 ranges from 2 date picker  ,  for example 1 month     2-The user choose Sunday, Tuesday and Thursday     , i want to push in an array  all Sundays dates , Tuesday dates and Thursday dates

Comment: Ok, so this has nothing to do with the data source, you simply want to end up with an array of 'all mondays between start and end dates`?

Comment: If so, does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29091126/1772933

Comment: what if the range of dates are specified by user, i mean from day1 till 30 for example

Comment: at this point, you need to show the datasource and an example of some kind. Or at least a walkthrough: This is the data. User chooses a date range of X to Y. I want to sort the data by this user id, in this date range, and if the user clicks on monday, I want to sort the data further to only show results that happen on a monday. Please be clear